# Infragistics UltraTextEditor event on textchanged and leave?

Tags: infragistics

Is there an event for UltraTextEditor that fires only when the control looses focus and when its text has been modified?.

For example, Ultragrids have one called AfterCellUpdate and I am looking for something like that to a textEditor...Am I missing something here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Why is it important to know when you are leaving the control and the value has changed?  if you are doing validation, I would recommend using the Validating event.  If you are doing something else it would be better to understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two events called:

```
    private void UltraTextEditor_AfterExitEditMode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    private void UltraTextEditor_AfterEnterEditMode(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

the `AfterExitEditMode` is fired when the control exits edit mode, this event could be used alongside with the standard `ValueChanged` event to monitor the editing on the control.

As you can see these events have all the same signature and thus can be handled by the same event handler.